# Bhagya Suktam and translation in English

Tags: vedas, scripture, translation-request

Bhagya is a Sanskrit word which  means Destiny or Fortune, usually Blessed Destiny.

The origins of this Sanskrit word can be found in the Vedas.

Bhaga is referred to as a God who gifts Truth to a human being and guides the person towards Bliss.

It is understood that there is a Suktam by the name Bhagya Suktam in the Vedas.

What is Bhagya Suktam? What are the verses in Sanskrit? What is the translation in English?

Comment: Here is the suktam:http://www.bharatiweb.com/English/Bhaagya%20Sooktam%20v1.pdf. Here is the translation in english:http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Bhagya_Suktham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **ॐ**
>
> **परातरग्निं परातरिन्द्रं हवामहे परातर्मित्रावरुणाप्रातरश्विना |**
>
> **परातर्भगं पूषणं बरह्मणस पतिं परातः सोममुत रुद्रं हुवेम ||**
>
> **Aum**
>
> **prātaraghniṃ prātarindraṃ havāmahe prātarmitrāvaruṇāprātaraśvinā |**
>
> **prātarbhaghaṃ pūṣaṇaṃ brahmaṇas patiṃ prātaḥ somamuta rudraṃ huvema ||**
>
> MEANING In English:
>
> AGNI at dawn, and Indra we invoke at dawn, and Varuṇa and Mitra, and
>   the Aśvins twain.
>
> Bhaga at dawn, Pūṣan, and Brahmaṇaspati, Soma at dawn, Rudra we will
>   invoke at dawn.
>
> अर्थ हिंदी में:
>
> हम प्रात :  के समय पर अग्नि , वरुण ,इन्द्र  ,मित्र ,अश्विन कुमार ,भग ,
>   पूष,ब्रह्मनास्पति ,सोम ,रूद्र का आवाहन करते हैं
>
> **परातर्जितं भगमुग्रं हुवेम वयं पुत्रमदितेर्यो विधर्ता |**
>
> **आध्रश्चिद यं मन्यमानस्तुरश्चिद राजा चिद यं भगं भक्षीत्याह ||**
>
> **prātarjitaṃ bhaghamughraṃ huvema vayaṃ putramaditeryo vidhartā |**
>
> **ādhraścid yaṃ manyamānasturaścid rājā cid yaṃ bhaghaṃ bhakṣītyāha ||**
>
> Meaning in English :
>
> We will invoke strong, early-conquering Bhaga, the Son of Aditi, the
>   great supporter:
>
> Thinking of whom, the poor, yea, even the mighty, even the King
>   himself says, Give me Bhaga
>
> अर्थ हिंदी में:
>
> हम शक्तिशाली , युद्ध में जीतने वाले भग का आवाहन करते हैं जिनके बारे
>   में सोचकर राजा  भी कहते हैं की हमें भग दीजिये
>
> **भग परणेतर्भग सत्यराधो भगेमां धियमुदवा ददन नः |**
>
> **भग पर णो जनय गोभिरश्वैर्भग पर नर्भिर्न्र्वन्तः सयाम ||**
>
> **bhagha praṇetarbhagha satyarādho bhaghemāṃ dhiyamudavā dadan naḥ |**
>
> **bhagha pra ṇo janaya ghobhiraśvairbhagha pra nṛbhirnṛvantaḥ syāma ||**
>
> Meaning In English
>
> Bhaga our guide, Bhaga whose gifts are faithful, favour this song, and give us wealth, O Bhaga. Bhaga, augment our store of kine and
>   horses, Bhaga, may we be rich in men and heroes.
>
> अर्थ हिंदी में:
>
> हे भग हमारा मार्गदर्शन करें ,आपके उपहार अनुकूल हैं ,हमें ऐश्वर्य
>   दीजिये हे भग ! हमें घोडे {सवारी } और योधा रिश्तेदार  दीजिये
>
> **उतेदानीं भगवन्तः सयामोत परपित्व उत मध्ये अह्नाम |**
>
> **उतोदिता मघवन सूर्यस्य वयं देवानां सुमतौ सयाम ||**
>
> **utedānīṃ bhaghavantaḥ syāmota prapitva uta madhye ahnām |**
>
> **utoditā maghavan sūryasya vayaṃ devānāṃ sumatau syāma ||**
>
> Meaning In English
>
> So may felicity be ours at present, and when the day approaches, and
>   at noontide;
>
> And may we still, O Bounteous One, at sunset be happy in the Deities'
>   loving-kindness.
>
> अर्थ हिंदी में:
>
> कृपा कीजिये कि अब हमें  सुख-चैन मिले , और जैसे जैसे दिन बढ़ता जाये ,
>   जैसे -जैसे दोपहर हो , शाम हो हम देव कृपा से प्रसन्न रहे
>
> **भग एव भगवानस्तु देवास्तेन वयं भगवन्तः सयाम |**
>
> **तं तवा भग सर्व इज्जोहवीति स नो भग पुरेता भवेह ||**
>
> **bhagha eva bhaghavānastu devāstena vayaṃ bhaghavantaḥ syāma |**
>
> **taṃ tvā bhagha sarva ijjohavīti sa no bhagha puraetā bhaveha ||**
>
> Meaning In English :
>
> May Bhaga verily be bliss-bestower, and through him, Gods! may
>   happiness attend us.
>
> As such, O Bhaga, all with might invoke thee: as such be thou our
>   Champion here, O Bhaga.
>
> अर्थ हिंदी में:
>
> हे भग आप परमानंद प्रदान करें और आपके द्वारा देव हमें प्रसन्नता से
>   स्वीकार करें हे भग हम आपका आवाहन करते हैं ,आप यहाँ हमारे साथ आयें
>
> **समध्वरायोषसो नमन्त दधिक्रावेव शुचये पदाय |**
>
> **अर्वाचीनं वसुविदं भगं नो रथमिवाश्वा वाजिन आ वहन्तु ||**
>
> **samadhvarāyoṣaso namanta dadhikrāveva śucaye padāya |**
>
> **arvācīnaṃ vasuvidaṃ bhaghaṃ no rathamivāśvā vājina ā vahantu ||**
>
> **Meaning In English :**
>
> To this our worship may all Dawns incline them, and come to the pure
>   place like Dadhikrāvan.
>
> As strong steeds draw a chariot may they bring us hitherward Bhaga who
>   discovers treasure
>
> अर्थ हिंदी में:
>
> इस प्रकार प्रतिदिन भग यहाँ आयें {पवित्र स्थान जैसे दधिक्रावन }जैसे
>   शक्तिशाली घोड़े रथ को खींचते हैं वैसे ही भग का यहाँ आवाहन  किया जाये
>
> **अश्वावतीर्गोमतीर्न उषासो वीरवतीः सदमुछन्तु भद्राः |**
>
> **घर्तं दुहाना विश्वतः परपीता यूयं पात ... ||**
>
> **aśvāvatīrghomatīrna uṣāso vīravatīḥ sadamuchantu bhadrāḥ |**
>
> **ghṛtaṃ duhānā viśvataḥ prapītā yūyaṃ pāta ... ||**
>
> Meaning In English
>
> May blessed Mornings dawn on us for ever, with wealth of kine, of
>   horses, and of heroes,
>
> Streaming with all abundance, pouring fatness. Preserve us evermore,
>   ye Gods, with blessings.
>
> अर्थ हिंदी में:
>
> इस प्रकार कृतार्थ सुबह हमें प्राप्त हो हमें  हमें घोडे और योधा
>   रिश्तेदार  प्राप्त हो हे देव हमें अपने आशीर्वाद दीजिये

[Source](http://vedicsuktams.blogspot.in/2011/03/bhagya-suktam-rigved-7-41.html)

Answer (score 2):

> ऊँ प्रातरग्निं प्रातरिन्द्रं हवामहे प्रातर्मित्रा वरुणा प्रातरश्विना ।
>   प्रातर्भगं पूषणं ब्रह्मणस्पतिं प्रातस्सोममुत रुद्रँ हुवेम ॥1॥
>
> Aum praataragniṃ praatarindraṃ havaamahe praatarmitraa varuṇaa
>   praatarashvinaa | praatarbhagaṃ pooṣhaṇaṃ brahmaṇaspatiṃ praatass
>   somamuta rudraṃ huvem ||1||
>
> 1. At dawn, we invoke Agni (the fire deity), Indra (the rain deity), Mitrā (the Sun) and Varuṇa (the deity of the ocean); the Aśvins (the
>      celestial physician twins), Bhaga (the deity of wealth), Puṣan (the
>      Sun as the deity of nutrition), Bṛahmaṇaspati (the preceptor of the
>      gods), Soma (the Moon), and Rudra (the god of dissolution)
> 2. हम प्रात: के समय पर अग्नि , वरुण ,इन्द्र  ,मित्र ,अश्विन कुमार ,भग , पूष,ब्रह्मनास्पति ,सोम और रूद्र का आवाहन करते हैं
>
> प्रातर्जितं भगमुग्रँ हुवेम वयं पुत्रमदितेर्यो विधर्ता । आद्ध्रश्चिद्यं
>   मन्यमानस्तुरश्चिद्राजा चिद्यंभगं भक्षीत्याह॥2॥
>
> Praatarjitaṃ bhagmugraṃ huvem vayaṃ putramaditeryo vidhartaa | 
>   aadhrash chidyaṃ manya maanastu rashchidraajaa chid yaṃ bhagaṃ
>   bhakṣhityaaha ||2||
>
> 2. We invoke at dawn, the fierce Bhaga, the son (manifestation) of Aditi (the Cosmic Power), who is the very sustainer of the creation.
>      Whether a pauper, a busy person, or a king; everyone worships and
>      contemplates upon Bhaga saying, 'I would worship Bhaga.'
> 3. हम शक्तिशाली , युद्ध में जीतने वाले भग का आवाहन करते हैं जिनके बारे में सोचकर राजा  भी कहते हैं की हमें भग दीजिये
>
> भग प्रणेतर्भगसत्यराधो भगेमां धियमुदवददन्नः। भगप्रणो जनय
>   गोभि-रश्वैर्भगप्रनृभि-र्नृवन्तस्स्याम ॥3॥ bhagha praṇetarbhaga
>   satyaraadho bhaghemaaṃ dhiyamudava dadannaḥ |  bhaga praṇo janaya
>   gobhirashvairbhaga pranṛibhirnṛivantassyaam ||3||
>
> 3. O Bhaga! The great leader, and truth is your wealth. Bestow it upon us, and elevate our intellect and protect it. Bless us with
>      cattle-wealth, horses, and descendants and followers.
> 4. हे भग हमारा मार्गदर्शन करें ,आपके उपहार अनुकूल हैं ,हमें ऐश्वर्य दीजिये हे भग ! हमें घोडे {सवारी }, गाय और योद्धा वंशज दीजिये
>
> उतेदानीं भगवन्तस्यामोत प्रपित्व उत मध्ये अह्नाम्। उतोदिता मघवन्
>   सूर्यस्य वयं देवानाँ सुमतौ स्याम ॥4॥
>
> utedaaneeṃ bhagavantasyaamot prapitv ut madhye ahnaam | utoditaa
>   maghavan sooryasya vayaṃ devaanaaṃ sumatau syaam ||4||
>
> 4. May we be blessed by Bhaga now (during this fire-ritual), and when the light approaches, or at midday. O Lord Indra! At sunset also, may
>      we still find favor of the Sun, and other gods.
> 5. कृपा कीजिये कि अब हमें  सुख-चैन मिले , और जैसे जैसे दिन बढ़ता जाये , जैसे -जैसे दोपहर हो , शाम हो हम देव कृपा से प्रसन्न रहे
>
> भग एव भगवाँअस्तु देवास्तेन वयं भगवन्तस्स्याम। तं त्वा भग सर्व
>   इज्जोहवीमि सनो भग पुर एता भवेह॥5॥
>
> bhaga eva bhagavaanastu devaastena vayaṃ bhagvantasyaam | taṃ tvaa
>   bhaga sarva ijjohaveemi sano bhaga pur etaa bhaveha ||5||
>
> 5. May Bhaga, (and) the gods be the possessor of good fortune, and through Him, may we may be blessed with good fortune by that god.
>      Everyone including myself invite you to bring in good fortune. O
>      Bhaga! Kindly lead us being present in the ritual.
> 6. हे भग आप परमानंद प्रदान करें और आपके द्वारा देव हमें प्रसन्नता से स्वीकार करें हे भग हम आपका आवाहन करते हैं ,आप यहाँ हमारे साथ आयें
>
> समध्वरायोषसोऽनमन्त दधिक्रावेव शुचये पदाय। अर्वाचीनं वसुविदं भगन्नो
>   रथमिवाश्वावाजिन आवहन्तु॥6॥
>
> samadhvaraayoshaso namanta dadhikraaveva shuchaye padaaya |
>   arvaacheenaṃ vasuvidaṃ bhaganno rathamivaaśhvaa vaajina aavahantu
>   ||6||
>
> 6. May the presiding deities of the early morning-hour arrive here, like the horse that puts its foot in the place of Vedic ritual for
>      establishing the fire altar. May they bring Bhaga, the Lord of wealth,
>      as speedily as swift horses pulling a chariot
> 7. इस प्रकार प्रतिदिन भग यहाँ आयें {पवित्र स्थान जैसे दधिक्रावन }जैसे शक्तिशाली घोड़े रथ को खींचते हैं वैसे ही भग का यहाँ आवाहन  किया जाये
>
> अश्वावतीर्गोमतीर्नउषासो वीरवतीस्सदमुच्छन्तु भद्राः। घृतं दुहाना
>   विश्वतः प्रपीनायूयं पात स्वस्तिभिस्सदा नः॥7॥
>
> ashhvaavateergomateerna uṣhaaso veeravateess sadamuchchantu bhadraḥ |
>   ghṛitaṃ duhanaa vishvataḥ prapeenaa yūyaṃ paata swastibhissadaa
>   naha||7||
>
> 7. May the presiding deities of the Dawn bless us with many horses and cattle, and plenty of milk and milk-products. May these auspicious
>      gods bless us with good progeny, and nourish all life. May they
>      proclaim auspiciousness in the place of worship. May they always
>      ensure our good fortune
> 8. इस प्रकार कृतार्थ सुबह हमें प्राप्त हो हमें  हमें सुपुत्र, घोडे, पशु, दुग्ध और योधा रिश्तेदार  प्राप्त हो हे देव हमें अपने आशीर्वाद
>      दीजिये

[Source](http://www.theastrojunction.com/2015/07/bhagya-suktam-a-powerful-hymn-to-improve-luck.html)

Comment: The answer is helpful.One answer has already been accepted.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ऊँ प्रातरग्निं प्रातरिन्द्रं हवामहे प्रातर्मित्रा वरुणा प्रातरश्विना ।
>
> प्रातर्भगं पूषणं ब्रह्मणस्पतिं प्रातस्सोममुत रुद्रँ हुवेम ॥१॥
>
> At dawn we invoke Fire God (Agni), Indra , Sun god(Mithra) ,
>
> God of rain(Varuna) and the two Aswini kumaras(Doctors)
>
> At dawn we invoke Bhaga(God of fortune), poosha(God of way),
>
> Brahmanaspathi (Teacher of devas) , Soma( moon God) and Rudra(God of
>   anger).
>
> प्रातर्जितं भगमुग्रँ हुवेम वयं पुत्रमदितेर्यो विधर्ता ।
>
> आद्ध्रश्चिद्यं मन्यमानस्तुरश्चिद्राजा चिद्यंभगं भक्षीत्याह॥२॥
>
> In the morning we make as our own Bhaga, who is the son of Adhithi and
>   a great  supporter,  And therefor even the gods who appear to be great
>   are making Bhaga  their own.
>
> भग प्रणेतर्भगसत्यराधो भगेमां धियमुदवददन्नः।
>
> भगप्रणो जनय गोभि-रश्वैर्भगप्रनृभि-र्नृवन्तस्स्याम ॥३॥
>
> Oh Bhaga , cross our way, Oh Bhaga who gives true gifts, continue
>   giving your  gifts,
>
> Oh Bhaga add cows and horses to our store, Oh Bhaga bestow on us men
>   and kings.
>
> उतेदानीं भगवन्तस्यामोत प्रपित्व उत मध्ये अह्नाम्।
>
> उतोदिता मघवन् सूर्यस्य वयं देवानाँ सुमतौ स्याम ॥४॥
>
> Make us one with wealth/luck and when light breaks and at noon,
>
> And even at sunset , let us be under the good grace of the gods.
>
> भग एव भगवाँ अस्तु देवास्तेन वयं भगवन्तस्स्याम।
>
> तं त्वा भग सर्व इज्जोहवीमि सनो भग पुर एता भवेह॥५॥
>
> Let Bhaga be the one who gives me wealth/luck , and Oh Gods, make us
>   lucky,
>
> Oh Bhaga we pray you with all our mind, that you bhaga be our leader
>   here.
>
> समध्वरायोषसोऽनमन्त दधिक्रावेव शुचये पदाय।
>
> अर्वाचीनं वसुविदं भगन्नो रथमिवाश्वावाजिन आवहन्तु॥६॥
>
> Let due to our worship at dawn , make them come to a pure place like
>   Dadikravan,
>
> Similar to strong horses leading the chariot , let Bhaga turn towards
>   us the  essence of riches
>
> अश्वावतीर्गोमतीर्नउषासो वीरवतीस्सदमुच्छन्तु भद्राः।
>
> घृतं दुहाना विश्वतः प्रपीनायूयं पात स्वस्तिभिस्सदा नः॥७॥
>
> Let the dawns be with us ,always safely with horses, cattle and
>   heroes,
>
> Milking the world with plenty and look after us ,Oh God with
>   blessings.
>
> यो माऽग्नेभागिनँ सन्तमथाभागं चिकीर्षति।
>
> अभागमग्ने तं कुरु मामग्ने भागिनं कुरु ॥८॥
>
> Oh Fire , the participating saints have offered the present offering
>
> Oh fire let that portion be made that of the participators.

[Source](http://anandjivananand.blogspot.in/2014/07/bhagya-suktam.html)